# How to draw a (helix shape) road for moving objects in unity3d?

Tags: graphics, unity-game-engine, game-engine

I am new to unity3d and I want to build a helix shape road for my game
How can I create a downward helix road ?is there any tutorial for it?
please clarify the steps to create road in general in unity3d if you can?

Answer (score 1):

I would create a single 360° part of that road *HelixPart* in Blender or whatever your favourite modelling tool is. Then import it into Unity.

Create an empty `GameObject` and attach a let's call it `HelixRoadCreator` Component:

```
public class HelixRoadCreator : MonoBehaviour {
    public int noOfParts = 5;
    public GameObject helixPartPrefab;
    void Start () 
         Vector3 newPosition = transform.position;
         for (int i = 1; i <= noOfParts; i++) {
             GameObject part = Instantiate (helixPartPrefab, newPosition, transform.rotation) as GameObject;
             part.tranform.parent = this.gameObject.transform;
             // recalculate newPosition, something like: newPosition += i* heightOfPart
         }
    }
}
```

Now drag your imported *HelixPart* on `helixPartPrefab` in `HelixRoadCreator` and adjust `noOfParts` to the number you want. Fiddle around to find out the right height calculation parameters et voilá.

Comment: I tried your code and it give mean error say :transform dosen't found in the current context ?

Comment: part.tranform.parent = this.gameObject; give me Cannot implicitly convert type `UnityEngine.GameObject' to `UnityEngine.Transform'

Comment: @Mohammed Don't forget `as GameObject` at the end of line. There was an error of course it should say **this.gameObject.transform**